# How to build a new column using for loop and if statement based on the values already present

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I want to create a new column and add values based on the value present in each row. below is the example

Sales  Result of new column
100    Low
200    Low
300    Moderate
400    High
500    High

Below is the code i tried to get result

```
data$New_Column = for (Sal in data$Sales){
  if(Sal > 300){
  print("High")
} else if(Sal == 300){
  print("Moderate")
}else{
  print("Low")
}
  
}
```

Thank You

Comment: It is considered polite to accept an answer that has answered your OP. This helps others who are looking for a solution for the same/similar query. Furthermore, people may be willing to help you in your future queries.

Answer (score 2):

You would usually not do that in a loop in R since most of the relevant functions can work directly with vectors.

Here is one option using `data.table::fcase()` and another using `ifelse()` from base R:

```r
library(data.table)

data$New_Column  <- fcase(
  data$Sales > 300, "High",
  data$Sales == 300, "Moderate",
  data$Sales < 300, "Low"
)

# Using base R only:
data$New_Column  <-
  ifelse(data$Sales == 300, "Moderate", ifelse(data$Sales > 300, "High", "Low"))

#   Sales New_Column
# 1   300   Moderate
# 2   500       High
# 3   200        Low
# 4   500       High
# 5   400       High
# 6   500       High
# 7   400       High
# 8   300   Moderate
```

Example input data

```
set.seed(13L)
data <- data.frame(
  Sales = sample(seq(100, 500, 100), size = 8L, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using mutate instead of a loop:

`newdat <- data %>>% mutate(New_Column, if(Sal==300 = "moderate"), ifelse(Sal>300, "High", "Low")`

Comment: Note that `if` is not vectorised, whereas `ifelse` is. Thus you would call `ifelse(Sal == 300, "moderate", ifelse(Sal  > 300, "High", "Low"))`. Also `Sal==300 = "moderate"` throws an error!

Comment: Dear Jamie,
Thanks for reverting, i tried, but the above solution is not generating the desired output.

Comment: Good catch David!  It looks like he got it.